# VHDL function call : External reference remains unsolved

Tags: functional-programming, system-verilog, verification, formal-verification, system-verilog-assertions

function within architecture as:

```
architecture rtl of entity1 is

...
function func(data_in:data_5bit) return d_5bit  is
    begin
    ...
    ...
 return ...;
 end;
 ...
end rtl;
```

I want to verify this function behaves as expected. So i have written a similar(not exact) function in my SVA file.

```
module verif(...);

...
...
function verif_func(input data_in);
....
return data_out;
endfunction

property property1;
seq1 ##1 seq2
|->
entity1.func(sig1) == verif_func(sig1);
endproperty
endmodule
bind entity1 verif verif_inst(.*);
```

But i get an error: "external reference func remains unresolved"

How can i add external reference in my Assertion file?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in VHDL to call a function which is in another scope using hierarchical naming.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to call a vhdl function from another scope without using hierarchical naming?

Comment: Not that I know of. VHDL is much more strict about scope than Verilog. Before 2008, there was nothing like hierarchical naming at all. The VHDL equivalent of hierarchical naming (_external names_) was introduced in VHDL-2008, but I don't think it allows you to call a function from another scope.

Comment: I was able to access a vhdl function from another file by :

    entity1.line__262.if_blk2.if_blk3.func.d_in;

As one can see, its dirty coding(using line number- as it can always change) and i want to change it with a better approach.

Comment: Really? That's news to me. What simulator are you using?

Comment: i am using Onespin 360, a formal verification tool.